# How do I depict x5 in a heat transfer problem with 9 nodes?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

[Visual of the problem and the heat transfer plates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuaTn.png)

The problem prompts: When studying heat transfer on a thin plate, it is common to be able to apply a particular temperature on each side of the plate. Temperatures in the center of the plate are approximated using the assumption that the temperature at each point is the average of the temperature at the four adjacent points. Under this hypothesis, create a system of equations to  approximate the temperature of the plates shown below at each of the nine interior points, then solve these systems to approximate the temperatures.

I understand the methodolgy and process of getting a system of equations. My only question is when getting to node x5 I get the equation of (x2 +x4 +x6+x8) / 4 = x5 (Please refer to visual if you can). For all the other equations I've been solving for the constants (e.g. (90 + 0 + x2 + z4) / 4 = x1 is the same as 4x1 - x2 -x4 = 90) How do I achieve the same result for x5?

I'm very sorry if this is a dumb question, it's my first time solving heat transfer problems like this. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You use the system of equations to get the result. Do you know how to do Gaussian elimination?

Comment: @CyclotomicField, that is the whole assignment but we were just introduced to the Gaussian elimination recently.

Comment: You'll want to set up the equations and use elimination. Most of the work is keeping the equations organized.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to write down all the equations and then solve the resulting linear system. While, for instance, in the first equation you get
$$
x_1 = \frac 14 (90+0+x_2+x_4) \Leftrightarrow x_1 -\frac 14 x_2 -\frac 14 x_4 = -\frac{45}{2}
$$

in the fifth equation you have
$$
x_5 = \frac 14 (x_2+x_4+x_6+x_8) \Leftrightarrow -\frac 14 x_2 - \frac 14 x_4 + x_5-\frac 14 x_6 -\frac 14 x_8 = 0
$$

but you can still assemble the system and solve it once you do this for all other points.